# Exception when running parallel async tasks that use EF Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to understand how to handle parallel async tasks that use entity framework when the db context has been injected into the class.

I have a dashboard that shows a number of totals, and what I'm trying to do is to run the methods that return those totals in parallel.  At the moment I have some code that looks like this:

```
public class KpiRepository : IKpiRepository
{
    private readonly kpiContext _context;

    public KpiRepository(kpiContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Task<int> NonCompliantTotalCountAsync()
    {
        return _context.vw_SearchData
            .CountAsync(x => x.NonComplianceDate < DateTime.Today || x.DateDueOutOfService < DateTime.Today);
    }

    public Task<int> NonCompliantInNextWeekCountAsync()
    {
        return NonCompliantBetweenNowAndDateCountAsync(DateTime.Today.AddDays(7));
    }

    public Task<int> NonCompliantInNextMonthCountAsync()
    {
        return NonCompliantBetweenNowAndDateCountAsync(DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1));
    }

    private Task<int> NonCompliantBetweenNowAndDateCountAsync(DateTime endDate)
    {
        return _context.vw_SearchData
            .CountAsync(x => (x.NonComplianceDate >= DateTime.Today && x.NonComplianceDate <= endDate)
                || (x.DateDueOutOfService >= DateTime.Today && x.DateDueOutOfService <= endDate));
    }

    var taskNonCompliantInNextWeekCountAsync = NonCompliantInNextWeekCountAsync();
    var taskNonCompliantInNextMonthCountAsync = NonCompliantInNextMonthCountAsync();  

    Task.WaitAll(
        taskNonCompliantInNextWeekCountAsync,
        taskNonCompliantInNextMonthCountAsync
    );

    data.NonCompliantInNextWeekCount= taskNonCompliantInNextWeekCountAsync.Result;
    data.NonCompliantInNextMonthCount= taskNonCompliantInNextMonthCountAsync.Result;
```

When I run that code I get this error from the `Task.WaitAll` line:

> InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The
>   connection's current state is connecting.

After [some reading](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Task-based%20Asynchronous%20Pattern%20support%20in%20EF.#ThreadSafety) I've realised that [Entity Framework is not thread safe](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Task-based%20Asynchronous%20Pattern%20support%20in%20EF.#ThreadSafety), so, I'm guessing what's causing the exception is that as each of my tasks are run they are all using the same instance of the context and that's causing EF to raise the exception?

The solution would therefore seem to be to create a new instance of the context for each task, but I'm using Dependency Injection so by default my context instance is scoped to the lifetime of the server request (I think).

So, is the above understanding correct, and if so, is the solution to get a new context for each of my tasks rather than reusing the existing one?  How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added a factory class to create new instances of my context:

```
   public class KpiContextFactory: IKpiContextFactory
    {
        private string _connection = @"Server=.\SQL2008EXP;Database=kpiDb;Trusted_Connection=True;";

        public KpiContext GetNewContext()
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<KpiContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connection);

            return new KpiContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
```

And now I just inject that factory instead of the context itself and then call `_kpiContextFactory.GetNewContext().[method]` instead of `_context.[method]`.  That seems to be working fine.